# How does filetype determination by filename extension in addition to XDG spec (mimeapps.list) work

Tags: mime-types, thunar, xdg-open, pcmanfm

I'm trying to set the default application for R noweb files but fail to find the place where this is specified. The reason for this is that my file managers seem to determine the file type by filename extension (.Rnw) rather than or in addition to the scheme specified by [freedesktop.org](http://standards.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.1.html) (that is: mimeapps.list, mimeinfo.cache, defaults.list...)

I tried pcmanfm and thunar as file managers. They agree in determination of the file type but differ from the `xdg-mime query filetype` utility. See below for minimal example and config files.

Moreover, the `xdg-mime` utility seems to ignore the local `mimeapps.list`, yet the filemanager honours it.

The **question** is: Is my assumption right that file types are determined by name extension in these file managers and where do I find the associated configuration?

I use Awesome WM as window manager an `pcmanfm` as desktop manager.

**Update:** I found [this tutorial on file extensions in pcmanfm](https://lkubaski.wordpress.com/2012/10/29/understanding-file-associations-in-lxde-and-pcmanfm/), but my problem is still that mime type and inferred type by `pcmanfm` don't match (`rnoweb.Rnw` is MIME type `text/plain`, `rnoweb0.Rnw` is `inode/x-empty`, yet `pcmanfm` lists both as `R Sweave file`)

**Update2 [SOLVED]:**
@mji proposed an xml file to be put in `~/.local/share/mime/packages`. This file already exists as `/usr/share/mime/text/x-r-sweave.Rnw`. It turns out that changing the `<comment>` tag in that file changes the Description column in thunar and pcmanfm. It also assigns the MIME type `x-r-sweave` to the files. I found this already in my question, but overlooked it (I searched for `x-r-noweb`)

---

Minimal example:

I created four files in an empty directory. Two empty, two with sample content:

```
touch plain0 rnoweb0.Rnw

cat > plain <<EOF
text
EOF

cat > rnoweb.Rnw <<EOF
<<>>=
1+1
@
EOF
```

I run `xdg-mime query filetype` and `xdg-mime query default` on these files to obtain the following results:

```
filename      MIME type           Default app
-------------------------------------------------
plain         text/plain          medit.desktop
plain0        inode/x-empty
rnoweb0.Rnw   inode/x-empty
rnoweb.Rnw    text/plain          medit.desktop
```

However, `thunar` and `pcmanfm` list the type of the `*.Rnw` files as "R Sweave file" and the `plain*` files as plain text document ("Einfaches Textdokument" in German). Default application listed in the file managers is `RStudio` for the `*.Rnw` and GVim for `plain*`.

Plain text files are opened with GVim, disagreeing with the `xdg-mime` utility but in accordance to settings in my local `.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

The only files on my system matching `locate mimeinfo` and `locate mimeapps` are

```
/etc/xdg/mimeapps.list
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
```

`grep`ping for the ocurrence of `rstudio` (rstudio.desktop) in these files yields (similar results summarized in `{...}`)

```
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache 
    application/x-r-data=rstudio.desktop;
    application/x-r-project=rstudio.desktop;
    text/css=rstudio.desktop;
    text/html=firefox.desktop;abiword.desktop;calibre-ebook-edit.desktop;rstudio.desktop;elinks.desktop;
    text/javascript=rstudio.desktop;
    text/x-R=rstudio.desktop;
    text/x-markdown=rstudio.desktop;
    text/x-r=rstudio.desktop;
    text/x-r-{doc,markdown,history,html,presentation,profile,source,sweave}\
    =rstudio.desktop;
    text/x-tex=texstudio.desktop;gvim.desktop;rstudio.desktop;
```

no other files mentioned in XDG spec contain any occurrence of `rstudio`.

`grep`ping for the `text/plain` MIME type, I obtain:

```
/etc/xdg/mimeapps.list : text/plain=medit.desktop;
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache : text/plain=medit.desktop;libreoffice-writer.desktop;gvim.desktop;abiword.desktop;
~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list : text/plain=gvim.desktop
~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list : text/plain=gvim.desktop;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Make the  mime-info file

```
$ vi ~/.local/share/mime/packages/x-r-noweb.xml

$ cat ~/.local/share/mime/packages/x-r-noweb.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
    <mime-type type="text/x-r-noweb">
        <comment>R noweb</comment>
        <glob pattern="*.Rnw"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

#### Update mime database

```
$ update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime/

$ xdg-mime query filetype rnoweb0.Rnw 
text/x-r-noweb
$ mimetype -d rnoweb0.Rnw
rnoweb0.Rnw: R noweb
$ mimetype rnoweb0.Rnw
rnoweb0.Rnw: text/x-r-noweb
```

#### Now, you can set the default application

```
$ xdg-mime default nice-app.desktop text/x-r-noweb
# (or edit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list)

$ xdg-mime query default text/x-r-noweb
nice-app.desktop
```

Comment: Thanks! This file exists (`/usr/share/mime/text/x-r-sweave.xml`) and determines the description column in thunar an pcmanfm. The default application was set in `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`. It works now! Only `xdg-mime` still reports something different (text/plain)