# wrong filetype for extension

Tags: mime-types, file-types

I have some octave files, ending with the default `.m` extension.

In file, I am getting it as ASCII text:

```
file euler.m 
euler.m: ASCII text
```

and plain text icon in nautilus.

How I can assign `.m`  filetype to octave/matlab?

Comment: Check this file: https://linux.die.net/man/5/magic

Comment: In the XDG model, you can define new mimetypes that take into account file extension via a glob pattern - see for example [How does filetype determination by filename extension in addition to XDG spec (mimeapps.list) work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205649/how-does-filetype-determination-by-filename-extension-in-addition-to-xdg-spec-m)

Answer (score 9):

That's not how `file` or nautilus works. The extension is not the file type. The mime type as detected from the file content is used for determining the MIME type, and that's what defines the symbol. That's better than what e.g. windows used to do, purely base its decision on extension, because, well, nautilus will show you a say word document as word document and open it with libreoffice, no matter whether its extension is .doc or .png or .txt.

Now, octave/matlab scripts *are* plain text files, and for historical reasons they're often restricted to ASCII only characters (there's no technical requirement for that, if I remember correctly).

So, all that might be missing is a detection magic for m-script that would enable file to recognize these program texts as program texts of this specific language.

Recognizing programming languages is not trivial. But it's not impossible either, as the fact that in many cases, `file` can tell C++ from python and even C source code just fine.

```
# octave/matlab script
# we'll just look for "function"; then make sure it's at the beginning of the line, followed by one or more space, followed by a function name, followed by possibly a space followed by an equality sign
0       search/8192     function
>0      regex   \^function[[:space:]]+[_[:alpha:]]{1,30}[[:space:]]*=    Matlab/Octave Source Code
!:mime  text/x-octave
```

This is a very rough check (which I haven't even tested), but it looks for m-script style function declarations. That's the best heuristic I can come up with.

Comment: Note that MIME Types are no longer called MIME Types, they are called Media Types. Also, the registration procedures have been *greatly* simplified, in particular through the introduction of vendor-specific and personal/experimental subtrees, so use of the old `X-` experimental prefix is discouraged. In particular, IANA says that if a Media Type that uses `X-` becomes popular, it might be registered under the name including the `X-`, so it is actually no longer guaranteed that anything starting with `X-` is unused. Its usage is replaced with the "unregistered" subtree.

Comment: But really, the "correct" version according to current best practices would be for the GNU project to register a vendor prefix with IANA (e.g. `gnu`), and then the Media Type for Octave would be something like `text/vnd.gnu.octave`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thank you for the inside. However, there is already a mim... Err media type on my system called text/x-octave with an x-matlab alias. So, using anything else would be consisting, not unifying, I'm afraid.